# I am facing issues in bootstrap grid while displaying data which may or may not appear

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am am facing issues in `bootstrap grid` while displaying data that may or may not appear. I am making two graphs in `react js`, one beside another.

First one is only visible/drawn when data appears, second is always visible. And all I want is that, while the first graph hasn't drawn, the second graph should take all `12` columns. If the first graph is drawn, the 2nd graph will revert back to `6` columns. Can someone help me with this?

Here is the code:

```
<div class="row d-flex flex-row d-flex">
         {audienceType?
         <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 flex-fill">
          <Portlet className="kt-portlet--height-fluid kt-portlet--border-bottom-brand">
            <PortletBody fluid={true}>
              <RealFake
                title="Followers Real vs Fake"
                desc="Check out each column for more details"
                dataS={audienceType}
              />
            </PortletBody>
          </Portlet>
        </div> :null}
        <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 flex-fill">
          <Portlet className="kt-portlet--height-fluid kt-portlet--border-bottom-brand">
            <PortletBody fluid={true}>
              <AudienceInterest
                title="Followers Based on their Audience Interest"
                desc="Check out each column for more details"
                dataS={
                 audienceInsights
                }
              />
            </PortletBody>
          </Portlet>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put condition for `classeName` values.

In your second graph div, you can do something like this:

```
className=`col-sm-12 col-md-6 ${audienceType? "col-lg-6" : "col-lg-12"} flex-fill`
```

You can change `classeNames` based on the state.